# phpmyadmin is denying me access when I try and use it through http://localhost/xampp homepage

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using a mac laptop running mac os x version 10.5.8 and I need to export a database to an .sql file so I can push it to github for a project. However when I attempt to use phpmyadmin for this through the localhost homepage, when I click on the link it responds with a page with just this error message:

MySQL said:

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

But it doesn't even prompt you for user information to begin with? is there something I am missing? someone please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your phpmyadmin configuration on the server.

You can see the documentation here: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#setup_script

The setting you are looking for is "$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']" - set this to 'HTTP', and you will be able to input a username and password.

Comment: Should be in config.inc.php - this is normally in the top level directory of phpmyadmin, wherever you have installed it.

Comment: ok, I found it. But when I try and change it, it says that I don't have the right priviliges. And when I go into the document info and change the settings so that everyone has read write it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with OS X, but have you turned off the web server first?  If the file is locked you may be unable to edit it.

Comment: um. wow. ok so the server wasn't off. I turned it off, but textedit still denied me access to the file. However I was able to save the changes in vim. However, the phpmyadmin link on localhost still denied my user. But if i manually typed in " http://localhost/phpmyadmin.index then i have access to the application. im just putting this up here in case it helps someone else. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the above error:-

a)  Open Mysql console from the tray of WAMP server

b)  It will ask for password(you might have set this password earlier when u installed MySql in your system)(In my case it is admin)

c)  Enter admin (press enter)
Now it means your phpmyadmin is assuming no password for your MySql and unable to connect MySql but yor are able to connect your MySql Server by providing password

For this Open config.inc file from the below path
C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14
And replace this line

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] =’ ’;
to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'admin';

I hope it will work..

Answer (score -1):

Turn off your Firewall and then connect to phpmyadmin. It should open. Then turn on Firewall again. Worked for me.